# How to fix SonarLint: Refactor this code to use the more specialised Functional Interface 'BinaryOperator<Float>'?

Tags: java, lambda, warnings, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

So im learning on how to use Lambda in Java and got the problem, that Sonar Lint is saying i should refactor the code to use the more specialised functional interface.

```
public float durchschnitt(float zahl1, float zahl2) {
    BiFunction<Float, Float, Float> function = (Float ersteZahl, Float zweiteZahl) -> (ersteZahl + zweiteZahl) / 2;
//  ^
//  Here I get the warning:
//  SonarLint: Refactor this code to use the more specialised Functional Interface 'BinaryOperator<Float>'
    return function.apply(zahl1, zahl2);
  }
```

All this little program should do is calculate the average of the two floats. The programm's working fine, but I want the warning to be gone. So how can I avoid that waring and fix the code?

Edit:
I oc tried finding a solution on google etc., but found none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BinaryOperator<T>` is in fact a subinterface of `BiFunction<T, T, T>`, and its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html) states *"this is a specialization of BiFunction for the case where the operands and the result are all of the same type"*, so just replace with:

```
BinaryOperator<Float> function = (Float ersteZahl, Float zweiteZahl) -> (ersteZahl + zweiteZahl) / 2;
```

Also no need to declare the `Float` argument types, it is auto-inferred by the compiler:

```
BinaryOperator<Float> function = (ersteZahl, zweiteZahl) -> (ersteZahl + zweiteZahl) / 2;
```